# jquery catch blur event on parent container

Tags: jquery, forms

Here's my problem:

I made a form-widget which shows a div containing several elements (textboxes).
when clicking outside that container, it should disappear - i already got that.
the problem now is: when clicking INSIDE the container, eg. for selecting a different textbox, the container will also disappear.
how can i prevent this?

my current code is:

```
showFormbutton.click(function() {
    showForm();
    $(document).one('click', function() { hideForm(); });
    return false;
});
```

cheers

Comment: Can you include your html and maybe a jsfiddle reproducing this?

Comment: could you provide some html? the $(document) is probably the wrong scope cause this will bind the click event on the document instead of the textboxes etc.

Comment: the problem is that i somehow need to add exclusions for the document.click event so that it won't fire ..

Answer (score 4):

The event bubbles up to `document`. You can see it like this: clicking in the container is also clicking in the document, since the container is part of the document. As such, the `document`'s click handler is executed when you click inside the container as well.

You can prevent this from happening by calling `e.stopPropagation` inside the container.

That way, clicking somewhere in the document outside the container *will* bubble up to the `document`'s click handler, but clicking in the container *will not* as the container's click event blocks this.

http://jsfiddle.net/6jRQZ/

```
$("#container").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Also, you can replace `function() { hideForm(); }` with `hideForm` - you can just pass the function; there is no need for an extra anonymous function.